ステータスバーの表示をコピーするコマンド
フィルターツールバーで指定する文字列に一致する行のみを表示させると、ステータスバーの左のほうに
288 行が一致しました。
といった表示が出ますが、これをコピーするコマンドはありませんか。
この表示にポインタを置き右クリックして [コピー] を選択すればコピーできますが、マウスを使わずにキーボードのショートカットキーでクリップボードに格納したいのです。

EmEditor v24.4 の現時点では、そのようなコマンドは用意されていませんが、以下のマクロを実行することで可能です。
var s = status;
if( s.length ) {
    clipboardData.setData("Text", s );
}

上記のマクロを、適当なファイル名、例えば CopyStatus.jsee という名前で保存します。
EmEditor の [マクロ] メニューの [選択] から、保存したマクロを選択します。
[マクロ] メニューの [実行] (または Ctrl + Shift + P) を選択します。すると、マクロが実行されます。
マクロを好きなショート カット キーに割り当てるには、以下のトピックを参考にしてください。
EmEditorでマクロファイルごとにホットキーを割り当てることはできますでしょうか？

お示しのマクロをショートカットキーで実行することができました。重宝いたします。
